# How to make a scrapy spider run multiple times from a tornado request

Tags: python, scrapy, tornado

I have an `Scrapy Spider` that I need to run when a Tornado `get` request is called. The first time I called the `Tornado` Request, the spider runs ok, but when I make another request to the `Tornado`, the spider does not run and the following error is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/Sebastian/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1413, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
    File "server.py", line 38, in get
        process.start()
    File "/Users/Sebastian/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 251, in start
        reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
    File "/Users/Sebastian/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1193, in run
        self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
    File "/Users/Sebastian/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1173, in startRunning
        ReactorBase.startRunning(self)
    File "/Users/Sebastian/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 684, in startRunning
        raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
ReactorNotRestartable
```

The tornado method is:

```
class PageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        process = CrawlerProcess({
            'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
            'ITEM_PIPELINES' : {'__main__.ResultsPipeline': 1}
        })

        process.crawl(YourSpider)
        process.start()

        self.write(json.dumps(results))
```

So the idea is that always that `DirectoryHandler` method is called, the spider runs and perform the crawling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after googled a lot of time, finally I get the answer to solve this problem... 
There is a library ***scrapydo*** (https://github.com/darkrho/scrapydo) that is based on croched and block the reactor for you allowing the reuse of the same spider every time is needed.

So to solve the problem you need to install the library, then call the setup method one time and then use the *run_spider* method... The code is like:

```
import scrapydo
scrapydo.setup()


class PageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        scrapydo.run_spider(YourSpider(), settings={
            'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
            'ITEM_PIPELINES' : {'__main__.ResultsPipeline': 1}
        })

        self.write(json.dumps(results))
```

Hope this could help anyone that have the same problem!

Comment: This is golden information! I have been battling with scrapy's reactor in my Django app for several hours as I was trying to run the same spider multiple times without restarting my server every time, but could not. This simple library fixed my problem. Thank you so so much!